# Springboot 2.3 docker image builds two images

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Using springboot 2.3 and mvn spring-boot:build-image command, I see
that two images with same image ID, but different repository were generated:
I'm using following pom.xml configuration for image name:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <image>
      <name>${container.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</name>
    </image>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The output of the docker images command is:

```
REPOSITORY                         TAG                     IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
330 MB
xx/microservicex                   latest                  20a6414c5a1a        41 years ago        305 MB
docker.io/xx/microservicex         latest                  20a6414c5a1a        41 years ago        305 MB
```

How to skip generation of second (alias?) image?

Comment: Are you sure that these are both of the same build?

Comment: Yes, the id is the same, also, before build I deleted all existing images.